# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. on django

Tags: django, django-views, django-registration

I am following Django 1.3 Web Development. and for logins, i am getting the following error

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

This is my settings.py Included APPS. It is exactly how the book says it should be.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangocricket.Cricket',
    'djangocricket.cms'
)
```

The book says, it should contain, django.contrib.auth.views.login .. and i am including it in

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'djangocricket.Cricket.views.index', name='default'),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', 'djangocricket.Cricket.views.user_home', name='user home'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    # url(r'^djangocricket/', include('djangocricket.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^news/', 'djangocricket.cms.views.index', name='index'),
    #url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 'djangocricket.cms.views.detail', name='get_single_news_item'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and my registration/login.html ... copy pasted from the book. it should do.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Bookmarks - User Login</title>
</head>
<h1>User Login</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match.
        Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i missing?

Comment: If someone needs to avoid `CSRF verification` ( for some reasons), [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50616651/8283848) might be useful

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to add the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag as a child of the `form` element in your Django template.

This way, the template will render a hidden element with the value set to the CSRF token. When the Django server receives the form request, Django will verify that the token matches the value that was rendered in the form. This is necessary to ensure that POST requests (i.e. data-altering requests) originate from an authentic client session.

For more info, check the Django documentation at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/

Here is an overview of the Cross-Site Request Forgery attack:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `csrf_token` template tag and the problem not solved, check `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting. You should set it to `None` on development environment.

Comment: Check `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` as well if your dev server doesn't have ssl.

Comment: What should be the value in production?

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted give additional info on the topic. If it ever happens to you and you are sure that the token is injected in the form and the view functions are handling everything properly but the problem persists. Make sure that there is no javascript code disabling the input fields. Happened to me, after couple of hours of debugging, finally realized that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="pHK2CZzBB323BM2Nq7DE2sxnQoBG1jPl" disabled="">
```

Comment: Good point; the values of `disabled` form elements are not sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I solved this problem when i added the {% csrf_token %}. Finally my code is this:

```
 <form id='formulario2' method='post' action=''>
      <h3>Enter:</h3>
      {% csrf_token %}


     <input id="id_mesaje" name="mesaje" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
    <input type='submit' name="boton2" value='Suscribete' style="display:inline-block;background-color: #80e174; "/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `csrf_token` to your POST form:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

In Django 4.0, it is important to have `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` set up as well.
See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

inside your form. This worked out for me. So why do we use the Cross-site  requested forgery?

Well, the answer is pretty simple, it just added another security layer to your web page, whereby any malicious user cannot validate a request using a wrong token.

Answer (score 0):

In your template after the form tag, you must and should put the CSRF token in a jing format on your template. For example {% csrf_token %}.

**In any template that uses a POST form, use the csrf_token tag inside the  element. If you don't want to use the csrf_token then you can disable it from your settings file of the main app.**

For your template just use

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
 //followed by rest of the tags
</form>
```