# csrf_token not found django ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-csrf

```
<script>
    function post(e) {
        data = $("#form_add_post").serialize();
        $.post( "/post/", function( data ) {
                alert("posted");
        });
        return false;
    }
    function addPost(){
    $(".matter").html("<form id='form_add_post' onsubmit='return post(event);'>{% csrf_token %} <table> <tr> <td class='heading'>Title: </td> <td class='box'><input type='text' name='title'></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan='2'><textarea class='data' name='content'></textarea></td> </tr> </table> <input id='submitt1' type='submit'> </form>");
}
</script>
```

I am trying to perform a AJAX post call. I have placed the csrf_token too. I have cross checked the data that is being sent. It is showing the entire details including the csrf_token.
**My data:**

> csrfmiddlewaretoken=foYqu9LrR25AomOmcFkaEicmN3CU2wcRNVg1gRPgl2F9XfL6IWerpbSK6TUKd4Ke&title=Tester&content=hhgj%3B%3Bhghjbjn

But i am getting a 403 error showing

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

[image: Image showing the error]

Comment: Take a look at this link [https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the request this way

```
$.ajax({
        type:form.attr('method'),
        url:form.attr('action'),
        data:form.serialize(),
        success: function(){
          ...
        }
      });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. May i know what is the problem in the code i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) you should add CSRF Tokens in Ajax Requests like this:

HTML Code:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

JS Code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

> In case of Django - You need to add the `{% csrf_token %}` template
>   tag as a child of the form element in your Django template. See this -
>   [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692625/csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-on-django)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) incorrectly. If you look at the request in your developer tools, I think you'll see that the post data is empty.

The second argument should be the request data, and third argument is the `success` callback.

```
$.post("/post/",
       data,
       function (response_data) {
         alert("posted");
       }
);
```

Once you've fixed that, [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) show how to include the CSRF token as a header in ajax requests, so you don't have to include it in the form body.