# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted - Shopping cart configuration

Tags: django, bitnami, openedx

I'm trying to enable Payment module for courses and when I'm clicking checkout, I'm getting "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." . I've tried adding my domain to "Home › Cors_Csrf › X domain proxy configurations › XDomainProxyConfiguration()" in Django admin panel. Even modified lms.env.json to add "ENABLE_CROSS_DOMAIN_CSRF_COOKIE": true, " ... still facing the issue. Can anyone please help.

Google group message link : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/edx-code/4VnLJG-raPE/llF1PDG9AQAJ

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you're not including the CSRF token in your form. In your template, it should look like:

```
<form action="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>
```

I don't know the library you're using, that was just general Django commentary. Hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: I'm directly using Openedx opensource software. I've checked request headers and there is CSRF token being passed in request headers

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692625/csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-on-django?rq=1

Comment: I'll check the link. Thanks for your help Sam.