# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-csrf, django-rest-framework-jwt

halo
i'm working on a project, using drf, but i'm getting CSRF verification failed. Request aborted   at first everything was working, but now when i test my api i keep keep getting,CSRF verification failed
below is my setting codes

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
   ),
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': [("%Y-%m-%d")],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ),
    
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100

}
```

views

```
class createProfileView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class   = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes= [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def create(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=request.data, instance = request.user.user_profile 
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        res  = {
            'msg' : 'Profile successfully created',
            'status':status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            'headers': headers,
            'data': serializer.data,
            
        }
        return Response(res)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

can anyone help out

Comment: I believe this question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692625/csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-on-django?rq=1)

Comment: i'm creating api while he's not